how to use the glossaries package like the xr package
I would like to have a separate latex document, say B, produce the glossaries (an index of symbols in my case) for document A (with the page numbers for document A).  So basically I would like to have the functionality of the xr package but then for the glossaries package.  I'm aware of \loadglsentries but that gets confused by the surrounding latex.
What are my options?   Thanks!!!

can't you just run makeglossaries as usual on document A (
but with no \printglossary and then input the generated glossary into document B ?

No, doesn't work.  Will produce a MWE to illustrate.
